# How to format features for SVM for human recognition?

Tags: matlab, svm, activity-recognition

I am using the Eigenjoints of skeleton features to perform human action recognition by Matlab.

I have 320 videos, so the training data is 320x1 cell array, each one cell contains Nx2970 double array, where N is number of frames (it is variable because each video contains different number of frames), 2970 is number of features extracted from each video (it is constant because I am using same extraction method for all videos).

How can I format the training data into a 2d double matrix to use as input for an SVM? I don't know how to do it because SVM requires double matrix, and the information I have is one matrix for each video of different sizes.

Comment: What is N? The number of features? The number of frames? Could you explain in more detail what is in your cell array? For example, it is a Nx2970 cell array where N is the number of video frames, 2970 is the number of feature dimensions, and each cell contains a double.

Comment: Why not to cast a cell array to a double using cell2mat function?

Comment: @ madbitloman, I tried cell2mat, but it will not be similar to the labels array. I want to have 320x1 labels array, and 320x2970 data array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear about how you want to go about classifying human motion from your video. You have two options,

1. Look at each frame in isolation. This would classify each frame separately. Basically, it would be a pose classifier
2. Build a new feature that treats the data as a time series. This would classify each video clip.

---

**Single Frame Classification**

For the first option, the solution to your problem is simple. You simply concatenate all the frames into one big matrix.

Let me give a toy example. I've made `X_cell`, a cell array with a video with 2 frames and a video with 3 frames. In your question, you don't specify where you get your ground truth labels from.  I'm going to assume that you have per video labels stored in a vector `video_labels`

```
 X_cell = {[1 1 1; 2 2 2], [3 3 3; 4 4 4; 5 5 5]}; 
 video_labels = [1, 0];
```

One simple way to concatenate these is to use a for loop,

```
X = [];
Y = [];
for ii = 1:length(X_cell)
     X = [X; X_cell{ii}];
     Y = [Y', repmat(video_labels(ii), size(X_cell{ii},1), 1)];
end
```

There is probably also a more efficient solution. You could think about vectorizing this code if you need to improve speed.

---

**Whole Video Classification**

Time series features are a course topic all in themselves. Here the simplest thing you could do is simply resize all the video clips to have the same length using `imresize`. Then vectorize the resulting matrix. This will create a very long, redundant feature.

```
num_frames = 10; %The desired video length
length_frame_feature = 2;
num_videos = length(X_cell);
X = zeros(num_videos, length_frame_feature*num_frames);
for ii=1:length(X_cell)
    video_feature = imresize(X_cell{ii}, [num_frames, length_frame_feature]); 
    X(ii, :) = video_feature(:);
end
Y = video_labels;
```

For more sophisticated techniques, take a look at [spectrograms](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html).

Comment: Hi 2cents, I can understand your answer, but my data is bit different. I have for each video 128x3xN where N is number of frames and it is variable among videos. How I can use imresize with 3D array which contains different number of frames ? Shall I use constant N among all videos ?

Comment: Yes, you want to resize the videos to all be the same length. If the videos have very different lengths, you might want to split them into multiple video clips instead of using `imresize`. In my example for whole video classification, I use `num_frames` to resize all videos to a constant N. Take a closer look at the for loop.

Comment: I am sorry, but let me ask you again. I have the X_cell 3D array, and imresize won't work with it. Secondly, do you think I should trim frames to specific number ? take the first 10 frames for example of each video ?

Comment: Ah, I understand. Usually, it is not necessary to maintain 2 dimensions for your features (128x3). You should just be able to flatten them into a (384x1) array. Then each video will be (384xN). Resizing along the N dimension will interpolate between features in adjacent frames.

Comment: Back to video length. Yes, you either need to decide to take the first N frames of every video (or the center N frames), or you need to resize the videos so that they are all N frames long using interpolation (imresize).

Comment: I tried your suggestions, and it gives me 20% accuracy. I am sure there is something wrong! Did you try applying SVM ? using BOW technique ?

Comment: You are asking me whether I got similar accuracy? I don't have access to your dataset. I'm simply describing standard approaches for building video feature descriptors. In classification tasks, something rarely works straight off the shelf. If you think your features are not powerful enough, you can try more sophisticated techniques, but you will need to find a reliable way to make all your video features the same length or you will not be able to use an SVM.

Comment: If you need more information about video feature design, I would recommend looking at scholarly papers about human action recognition features. They will be tough to read, but they will lay out how the authors choose the video clip length, whether they used overlapping video clips, how they calculated per frame features, etc.

Comment: On second thought, are you using a multiclass SVM? Because if you are making a binary classification it shouldn't be possible to get less than 20% accuracy. If you are really getting 20% accuracy on a binary problem, you could just flip all the class assignments and get 80% accuracy. If you are using a binary classifier, I would suggest asking another question about your accuracy measurement.

Comment: Sorry typo there. It shouldn't be possible to get less than 50% accuracy with a binary classifier. Caveat: (1) Unless the testing set has a different bias than the training set (2) Or the number of positive and negative examples is unequal.